# Using Bluetooth LE devices with same BDADDR

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

A lot of "cheap" bluetooth adapters unfortunately have the same address assigned to them.  If more than one client uses these adapters to connect to a common set of servers, what would the impact of the client having the same address be?

My understanding is once the ADV_CONNECT_REQ sets up the connection with the Access Address and after that the BDADDR is not used.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For BLE, the BD address is used only when scanning/advertising and initiating connections. Once a connection has been established, the BD address is not sent explicitly in any packets. So in practice, if you have two devices with the same BD address, you can theoretically have two separate connections, one for each device. However these sessions won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Note that since Bluetooth 4.2, it is no longer allowed to have more than one connection to the same BDADDR.

Comment: Also, when performing the BLE pairing using SMP, the BDADDR is used internally to confirm identity.